# DUPLICATE KEY error when inserting data in loop

Tags: java, mysql, database

I'm working on a java program and I'm encountering a `DUPLICATE KEY` error resulting in inconsistent data.

When I input this: 91, 96, 97; 98, 92; 93, 94, 99, 88 I expect the following in my database:

```
-------------------------------------
| ASSIGN_NO | UNIT_NO | ASSIGN_MARK |
-------------------------------------
| 0         | 100     | 91          |
| 1         | 100     | 96          |
| 2         | 100     | 97          | // end of unit 1
| 0         | 101     | 98          |
| 1         | 101     | 92          | // end of unit 2
| 0         | 102     | 93          |
| 1         | 102     | 94          |
| 2         | 102     | 99          |
| 3         | 102     | 88          | // end of unit 3
-------------------------------------
```

But I either end up with a "DUPLICATE PRIMARY KEY FOR 1-101" error or everything in the ASSIGN_MARK part is 0 except for the mark at the end (the 97, 92, 88) IN THIS CASE.

Here is a result I end up with instead:

```
+-----------+---------+-------------+
| ASSIGN_NO | UNIT_NO | ASSIGN_MARK |
+-----------+---------+-------------+
|         1 |     101 |          90 |
|         2 |     102 |          90 |
|         7 |     100 |          97 |
|         8 |     100 |          96 |
|         9 |     100 |         100 |
+-----------+---------+-------------+
```

My code is below:

```
public int InputAssign(int Assign) { 
  System.out.println("Assign is " + Assign); // system check 
  String[] Assignments = new String[Assign]; 
  int[] AssignmentsLOL = new int[Assign];
  for (int i = 0; i < Assign; i++) {
    System.out.println("For Assignment " + (i+1)); // system check
    Assignments[i] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Mark of Assignment "+ (i+1));           
        
    if (Assignments[i] != null) {
            
        try {
        AssignmentsLOL[i] = Integer.parseInt(Assignments[i]);
    
// MYSQL CODE STARTS HERE /////////////////////////////////////////////////

        
        try {
                    
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/grades";
        String username = "root";
        String password = "///////";
                    
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        String sql1 = "INSERT INTO assignments (ASSIGN_NO, UNIT_NO, ASSIGN_MARK) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
        PreparedStatement statement1 = connection.prepareStatement(sql1);
                    
        statement1.setInt(1, i);
        statement1.setInt(2, i + 100);
            statement1.setInt(3, AssignmentsLOL[i]);
        System.out.println("connection success!!");
                    
        int rows = statement1.executeUpdate();
        if (rows > 0) {
            System.out.println("Assignment Update Success!!");
                    }

// MYSQL CODE ENDS HERE /////////////////////////////////////////////////                       
        statement1.close();
        connection.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Assignment OOPS");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
                
        System.out.println("Assignment mark is " + AssignmentsLOL[i]); // system check
        if (AssignmentsLOL[i] < 0 || AssignmentsLOL[i] > 100) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Input out of bounds",
                                  "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
        } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
           System.out.println("input is not an int value"); 
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Input is not a number",
                              "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    System.exit(0);
                 }
            } else System.exit(0);
    }
    int sum = IntStream.of(AssignmentsLOL).sum();
    int average = (int) ((sum / Assign) * 0.7);
    return average;
}
```

**edit**: here's the structure for the grades database:
table assignment:
ASSIGN_NO int AI PK
UNIT_NO int PK
ASSIGN_MARK in

table unit:
UNIT_NO int PK
UNIT_W int
UNIT_FINAL int
UNIT_MARK int

Comment: it seems to be issue with value of `primary key` of `assignments` table, every insert statement should have unique `primary key`

Comment: @sanjeevRm shouldn't every iteration generate a new primary key though? At least, that's what I intend it to be.

Comment: Hey! And welcome to Stack Overflow. It looks like you're asking for help with your homework. While that is okay, it can cause a loss of focus. Stack Overflow works best when questions focus on one thing. I'm going to suggest that you change the focus of your question to the DUPLICATE PRIMARY KEY error you are experiencing.

Additionally, it would help your question if you provided the structure of your database, since that is required to reproduce your code problem.

Finally, I noticed you posted your database credentials. Remember to keep passwords safe and not to post them in public.

Comment: Yes, please provide the structure of the `grades` database table. This is needed to provide a full answer.

Comment: It can often be more helpful to split up the question into several.  If you think this is an SQL question, create just the SQL test case outside of any java program.  Once that's answered, if you still have a problem, it's probably related to the java program.  Create a separate test case just for the java program, without the SQL detail, since that was resolved by the first question.  If you have a JDBC issue, ask that separately.  Combining these potential issues into one question can cause confusion, loss of focus.  Debug the issue step by step.

Comment: Hi! I have added edits to include the structure of the database!

Comment: When are you getting this error? From the looks of your table structure it looks like your primary key is a combination of ASSIGN_NO and UNIT_NO which will work fine for your use case since you shouldn't be duplicating assignments. It sounds like you're not clearing the data between program launches so when you launch the program fresh it's trying to re-input assignments you put in last time. Since those have identical assignment and unit numbers they fail to insert. Does that make sense?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it starts happening during the inputs for unit 2, but I'll go make sure everything is cleared. Another thing that doesn't make sense is that ASSIG_NO is starting from 9 and going down rather than 0 and up. If you have any idea why this is happening.

Comment: Okay focus on the DUPLICATE KEY error. Once you have that one solved and you still have problems, make a new question with those problems, but first try to understand what you expected your program to do and why, and what it really did. 

Your code is a bit challenging to follow and understand because your methods fulfill more than one task at a time. It will be easier for you and other to debug it if you split the code into methods that do one function at a time. For example, you can extract the mysql code into a method like so: https://hastebin.com/pecacesoca.php

Comment: @CausingUnderflowsEverwhere thanks for the reply! I already solved the problem :D I have no idea what is different from the original but I changed around the return values for that one method so that I can integrate my code into my main body code part, where I have another segment of database code. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like in your database table structure you have set ASSIGN_NO as the primary key. This means values for it must be unique.

A database stores data that survives program restarts. Keeping this in mind, that means every time you call your InputAssign method, it will try to insert the same assignment numbers again since they always start from 0. This is where the DUPLICATE KEY error comes in.

Although switching your SQL command from `INSERT` to `REPLACE` may sound like a good idea to thwart the duplicate key error:

> REPLACE works exactly like INSERT, except that if an old row in the table has the same value as a new row for a PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE index, the old row is deleted before the new row is inserted. [¹](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replace.html)

This will result in inconsistent data for your use case.

If your program isn't expecting to have the data from the previous run stores in the database, you must clear the database entries at the start of your program.

Run a delete command on your database table at the start of your program to clear data stored from the last run
Here is an example code snippet to accomplish your needs:

```
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/grades";
    String username = "root";
    String password = "/////";
    try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        PreparedStatement statement1 = connection.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM assignments");
    ) {
        statement1.executeUpdate();
        System.out.println("connection success!!");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Deletion OOPS");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: I just noticed I misunderstood your problem while going through and editing your question. I will adjust my answer shortly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! My primary keys are both ASSIGN_NO and UNIT_NO though, I don't know if that makes a big difference or not.